# The layout_weight doesn't work as expected for a editfield

Tags: android

Below is my definition on a view layout on android. There are three component, a editfield, a button and a map. The textfield and button will be put together on a nested linearlayout which is located on the top of the view. And the map will be shown below the editfield. My problem is on the editfield width. I have specified the layout_weight to be 10 for the editfield and 1 for the button. However, the view will be shown as below screenshot. The width of the editfield is really small. I want it to be 10 times than the button width. How can I do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.lenovo.mds.lenovopoc.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="button"/>
</LinearLayout>

<com.amap.api.maps2d.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="7"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Add LinearLayout weightSum to 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give "match_parent" to LinearLayout. WeightSum is not mandatory. the problem is because of width="wrap_content". If you set the width to 'Match_parent" then it will align properly.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

**android:weightSum**

> Defines the maximum weight sum. If unspecified, the sum is computed by
>   adding the layout_weight of all of the children. This can be used for
>   instance to give a single child 50% of the total available space by
>   giving it a layout_weight of 0.5 and setting the weightSum to 1.0.

You should use `android:weightSum="11"`

**Finally**

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weightSum="11"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="button"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

android:weightSum="11" is the solution to your problem.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weightSum="11"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="button"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.amap.api.maps2d.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In parent layout of edittext you have to set width = "match_parent"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.lenovo.mds.lenovopoc.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="button"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.amap.api.maps2d.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You just need this.**

`Give match_parent to your LinearLayout and android:weightsum="11"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.lenovo.mds.lenovopoc.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="11">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="8" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.amap.api.maps2d.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`Here is screen shot how it Looks.`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it will work for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.amap.api.maps2d.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[this is the final output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUhrd.png)

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that the linear layout parent, dont set the height '0dp'. You need to put it match_parent. Also, other inside layout and button, i recommend do not put 0dp for height or width

Comment: Why do you think don't use 0pd? Is there any other solutions for layout components based on ratio value?

Comment: there is using relative layout